# create an xml with Excel

Tags: c#, xml, excel, linq

I am trying to create an XML file according to the headers in an Excel which created by users. I am trying to explain by a real example.

this is the excel format which is created by users. This template may change sometimes, that's why I am trying to create dynamically.

(cells are seperated by PIPE and these are placed in the first row.)

```
SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.NUMBER|SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.DATE|SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.ARP_CODE|SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.NOTES1|SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION.TYPE
```

this is the xml I need to create by excel above.

```
<SALES_ORDERS>
    <ORDER_SLIP DBOP="INS" >
        <NUMBER>...</NUMBER>
        <DATE>...</DATE>
        <ARP_CODE>...</ARP_CODE>
        <NOTES1>...</NOTES1>
        <TRANSACTIONS>
           <TRANSACTION>
               <TYPE>...</TYPE>
               .........
```

can anybody help me with this algorithm.

Comment: Not clear from that example how you'd handle repeats?  What if there are multiple (eg) ORDER or TRANSACTION tags ?

Comment: Good question, I forgot to mention that. If there are 2-3 TRANSACTION line, then there will be 2-3 lines in excel with same Headar Information

Comment: Is the intention that there's only a single top-level <SALES_ORDERS> element?  Do repeating lines (eg additional TRANSACTION's) contain the full set of information from the previous lines?  I think it would be helpful if you could upload a screenshot or make a sample data file available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not write on C a long time. I do not know if that helps. That code with php:

```
$string = "SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.NUMBER|SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.DATE|SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.ARP_CODE|SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.NOTES1|SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION.TYPE";
// Split the string by | to an array of pathes
     $arr = explode('|', $string);
     $xml = '';
     foreach ($arr as $s) {
// Split a string by the point char to an array of items
         $path = explode('.', $s);
// set the pointer to tho root of the xml array
         $p = &$xml;
// Walk along the path
         foreach($path as $item) {
// If this node does not exist
             if (!isset($p[$item])) {
// if this level does not exist (item parent is not an array), make it
                 if(!is_array($p)) $p = array();
                $p[$item] = ''; 
             }
 // move the pointer to this item 
             $p = &$p[$item];
         }
     }
     var_dump($xml);
```

output:

```
 array(1) { 
    ["SALES_ORDERS"]=> array(1) {
        ["ORDER_SLIP"]=> array(5) {
            ["NUMBER"]=> string(0) ""
            ["DATE"]=> string(0) ""
            ["ARP_CODE"]=> string(0) ""
            ["NOTES1"]=> string(0) ""
            ["TRANSACTIONS"]=> array(1) {
                ["TRANSACTION"]=> array(1) {
                    ["TYPE"]=> &string(0) ""
    } } } } }
```

**UPDATE** According to lack of response, algorithm in php you do not really understand. had to remember C. Correct under current trends :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define PATH '|'
#define NODE '.'
#define EOS 0
#define NULL 0

class node {
private:
    char    *name = NULL;
    node    *next = NULL, *down = NULL;
    //  data    *void = NULL;

public:
     node(char *word = NULL) { 
         this->name = word;  
}
     void echoNode(node *p, int level = 0) {
         char   *str;
         int    i;
         if (!p) return;
         i = level * 4; while (i--) cout << ' ';
         cout << "<";
         str = p->name; while (*str) cout << *str++;
         cout << ">";
         if (p->down) {
             cout << "\n";
             echoNode(p->down, level + 1);
             i = level * 4; while (i--) cout << ' ';
         }
         cout << "</";
         str = p->name; while (*str) cout << *str++;
         cout << ">\n";
         if (p->next) echoNode(p->next, level);
     }

    node * FindChild(char *word) {
        node *p = this->down;
        while(p) if (!strcmp(p->name, word)) break; else p = p->next;
        return p;
    }
    node * AddChild(char *word) {
        node *p = this;
        if(p->down) {
            p = p->down;
            while (p->next) p = p->next;
            p->next = new node;
            p = p->next;
        }
        else {
            p->down = new node;
            p = p->down;
        }
        p->name = word;
        return p;
    }
};

void main() {
    char str[] = "SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.NUMBER|SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.DATE|SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.ARP_CODE|SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.NOTES1|SALES_ORDERS.ORDER_SLIP.TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION.TYPE\x0";

    char    *p = str;
    char    *word;
    char    status;

    node    *xml = new node("root");
    node    *pxml, *t;

    do {
        pxml = xml;
        do {
            word = p;
            while (*p && *p != PATH && *p != NODE) p++;
            status = *p; 
            *p++ = EOS;
            if (!(t = pxml->FindChild(word))) pxml = pxml->AddChild(word);
            else pxml = t;
        } while (status && status != PATH);
    } while (status != EOS);
    xml->echoNode(xml);
}
```